# Can not get my parameter to work inside SELECT WHERE clause in python

Tags: python, sqlite, select, where-clause

So I made a function that takes as a parameter a string and then uses a select where clause to get the values for just that parameter, but for some reason it will not work. I've tried (ar), "ar", '%s'%ar
None of those are working for me please help

```
def getLoc(ar):
    cursor = conn.execute("SELECT location.name from area,location WHERE area.name = ***(ar)*** ")


get_locations_for_area("Columbia")
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the code formatting to make your question easier to read!
I think the way it would work is:

```
def getLoc(ar):
    cursor = conn.execute("SELECT location.name FROM area,location WHERE area.name = ?", (ar,))
```

What this does is, make the question mark correspond to the second argument of `conn.execute()`. Basically it's to put variables in as parameters of your query.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
def getLoc(ar):
    cursor = conn.execute("SELECT location.name from area,location WHERE area.name = ?", ar)
```

Check out the documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html, it tells you why to use the "?"

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should use this statement

cursor = conn.execute("SELECT location.name from area,location WHERE area.name = %s" %ar)

Comment: This is not a good idea. From python docs at https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html "You shouldn’t assemble your query using Python’s string operations because doing so is insecure"